# With the jQuery EasyUI datagrid,sending queryparameters

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

With the [jQuery EasyUI](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/#dg-properties), we can create a grid table with the queryparams.
here is the sample code

```
$('#dg').datagrid({
    queryParams: {
        name: 'easyui',
        subject: 'datagrid'
    }
});
```

However,what I am trying to achive is create queryparams inside the html tags
like the belove code

```
    <table id="tt" class="easyui-datagrid"
      url="Service.asmx/GetReportByFilter"
       rownumbers="true" pagination="true" data-options="singleSelect:true,collapsible:true,
method:'post'"
   queryparams="{name: 'easyui',subject: 'datagrid'}">

                        </table>
```

It seeems that this part  `queryparams="{name: 'easyui',subject: 'datagrid'}"` doent work.I mean no parameter to post the service called name and subject.It post only page and rows values

Comment: Just a guess.  Try putting queryParams : { name: 'easyui', subject: 'datagrid'} as another key value pair inside of the data-options attribute

Comment: I will try ,lets seee

Comment: you should try something like `data-options="singleSelect:true,collapsible:true,
method:'post',queryParams:{name:'easyui', subject:'datagrid'}"`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send some parameters to the url from the easyui grid, but not using the url, you can use the method=post and add the parameters in the queryParams, like this. Works for my!!

```
<table class="easyui-datagrid" style="width: 99%;;height:250px"
   url="views/action.php?table=employee&view=form&action=list-fields"
   toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true"
   rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true" pagePosition="top"
   data-options="onSelect:row_select,onUnselect:row_unselect,onSortColumn:sort_column,method:'post',queryParams:{employee_id:'7'}">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th field="name" width="60" sortable='true'>Name</th>
    <th field="value_list" width="40" sortable='true'>Value List</th>
    <th field="value" width="40" sortable='true'>Value</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: Can anybody share if they found a solution to this?? I am trying to pass a parameter to my php file, but it is not working with whatever I try. Please share if you have found a solution to this.